# How to animate the width of a div slowly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have navigation nested in a div that is offscreen to the left and when the user scrolls down the page and reaches pixel 296, the left navigation slowly appears by it's width growing towards the right.

What I have now is half working. The navigation nested in the div appears when the user scrolls down the page but I want it to animate slowly to the right and that is not happening. Not sure what I am doing wrong. The specific line I am having problems with is:

```
$("#slidebottom").animate({ width: "100" }, 'slow');
```

**But here is my entire code:**

```
$(window).scroll(function(){

  var wintop = $(window).scrollTop(), docheight = $(document).height(), 
  winheight =    $(window).height();

  var bottomHeight = $("#slidebottom").height();
  var zeroheight = 0;

  if  (wintop > 296) {
    bottomHeight = $('#slidebottom').height(docheight);
    $("#slidebottom").animate({ width: "100" }, 'slow');

  }

  if( wintop < 296)
  {
    bottomHeight = $('#slidebottom').height(zeroheight);    
    //$("#slidebottom").animate({ width: "0" }, 'slow');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 7):

The [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) show ints, not strings, as the arguments to width:

```
$("#slidebottom").animate({ width: 100 }, 'slow');
```

Edit: So I was wrong, that's not the problem; it handles strings just as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I must be doing something else wrong because that did not fix it. The div appears but does not grow in width slowly. Any other ideas? Thanks again.

Comment: I put together a super-simple jsFiddle, and it seems to work like I expect: http://jsfiddle.net/3b5qV/.  Maybe you could put your into a fiddle?

Comment: Thank you. Your code is definitely right and is working; but my entire code still does not work. I have to figure out what I am doing wrong. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following maybe?

```
$("#slidebottom").animate({ width: '100px' }, 'slow');
```

I have a feeling that the unit is important for this, since 100 can mean anything.  Not very specific.  And you can define this as a string just fine.  In fact, in the example they give for `.animate` it is defined as a string.

Comment: In the examples by jQuery themselves, it shows it with the units:  http://api.jquery.com/animate/  Maybe it isn't needed, but that is what they use.

Comment: Well I think jQuery parses your string first and extract the number part out then :P

Comment: I believe some css properties are dependant upon units in jQuery for cross browser compatibility, since jQuery returns some css properties with the units at the end of the values, it makes sense that it should be put back in there with the unit.  Maybe not for the `width` property, but definitely some others.

Comment: jQuery has to have numbers to work with to animate the properties. jQuery will later add the unit back in I think.

Comment: Thank you for your well thought out answer. It helps. Let me think about it. Thank you.